# How to upgrade glade 3.8 to glade 3.13 higher

Tags: glade

My glade 3.8 
My Ubuntu 12.04
How ? 
I'm newbier 
I'm try  but not working

Please ,help me !

Comment: You mean how to downgrading?

Comment: No,  upgrade ,  today  i'm used command: apt-get install glade   ...my glade is up to 3.12..Can I up to 3.16 ?  How ? please, i dont know how to install glade 3.16 ... can you help me?...

Comment: Dear all
Close topic from here. 
Thank everyone again :)

Answer (score 0):

First remove glade with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get remove glade
```

Download the last version of glade [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glade/).

Extract it somewhere, then just read the `INSTALL` file.

Comment: Nothing again't your answer, its that the Glade INSTALL file is utterly generic, and does not instruct how to build the program. There are like a million undeclared dependencies all of which seem to also not know how to install or operate themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as you said you are using Ubuntu 12.04 , I guess its using GTK+2 which is version 3.8 and latest. If you are using GTK+3 then Its version is 3.18 and latest.

You can install from source. Download the source and compile it. Link to download : https://glade.gnome.org/sources.html

How to compile from source ?

`./configure ; make ; sudo make install` will take care of everything.

If any errors coming up , google is there.